# Eclipse+ADTからAndroid Studioへの開発環境の移行について

Tags: android, java, eclipse, android-studio

今まで使っていたEclipse+ADTからAndroid Studioへ移行したいのですが､そのままandroid Studioをインストールしてしまって大丈夫なのでしょうか?
android Studioをインストールするときに､Select components to installという所で､選択してはいけない項目などありますか?  そこにはAndroid Studio本体､AndroidSDK, Android Virtual Device, Performanceという項目があるのですが､[こちら](http://qiita.com/seiya1311/items/924d8098db0d0b085f95)で書かれているようにSDKマネジャーとADVマネジャーが共存してしまいなにか不具合がしょうじないか心配です｡  またAndroidアプリでは無いのですが､今Eclipseで開発しているソフトウェアがありまして､そのまま開発を続けたいと考えております｡  そういった場合､Android Studioへ移行して開発を続けることは可能ですか?  
Eclipseでは､高速版のエミュレータもインストールしています｡

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます｡  android Studioをインストール出来ました｡  SDKは共有できるようです｡  また､日本語入力に関しては､issueにJDK1.8u25では解決しているとの記述がありましたのでJDKをアップデートすることで対応いたしました｡
しかし､Eclipseで作成したAndroidアプリをインポートすると､ADTのパスが違うというエラーが出たので､ビルドできませんでした｡  なので､こちらに関しては移行もEclipseを用いて編集するしかなさそうです｡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

共存自体は可能で、そのまま開発を続けることも出来ます。
私の経験上では、Android Studioで使うAndroid SDK(及び当該SDKを入れるためのManager)はEclipseで使用していたものと同じものを使うことが多いかと思います。(勿論、別々に入れても平気です。)
万が一既存のEclipseへの影響を絶対に与えたくない、ということで安全策を取るために別々のSDKなどを使用されるのであれば、パスの設定に気をつけてくださいね。(わかりやすい別の名前でパスを設定する、など)

それと、注意すべき点が一つあります。
Android Studio Ver.1がリリースされたタイミングでフォルダの構成として、
Android StudioとAndroid SDKのフォルダを別にしなければいけなくなりました。

Ver.1以前はこのような構成ではなく、同じフォルダの中に一緒くたにして扱っていたので、
もし以前のものをお使いの状態でインストールを進めようとすると、
Android StudioからSDK等々の移動を求められ、
その結果としてEclipse側で開発しているプロジェクトにも影響が出るかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

JDKの設定なら、[Android Studioが日本語入力中に落ちる](http://romly.com/archives/2014/09/android_studio_crashes_by_ime_and_jdk8.html)みたいな話が***あった***そうです。AndroidはまだJavaSE8相当のソースコードはライブラリ等使わないとコンパイルできないのでAndroidStudioの開発には不要と存じますが、Eclipseで開発していた場合、JDK7とJDK8の併用は問題となるのではないでしょうか……[今年の四月で7のサポートが切れることを今思い出しました。](https://java.com/ja/download/faq/java_7.xml)

AndroidStudioは安定版がリリースされましたが、開発は日々進んでおります。英語にご堪能であればAndroidStudioの[リリース状況](http://tools.android.com/release)や[issue](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)を直接ご確認いただけば、現在の最新SDKバージョン、エラー解決方法など掲載されておりますので、不安解消の材料に繋がるかと存じます。

Answer (score 0):

こちらで確認できる限りではその二つのソフトは違うandroid　SDKを使っているようで、不具合は起きなかったので大丈夫だと思います。